# Angular2 ngClass not working on click with Closing class

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular2-template

I have an accordion,it has 2 classes for Opening and Closing. On opening the class is working fine but for closing, it is taking the class but function over that css class is not working. 
Here is my

**HTML code**:

```
<div class="slideInDown" [ngClass]="{slideInDown: groupUser?.isOpen, 'slideOutUp':  !groupUser?.isOpen}">
```

**CSS:**

Opening Class:

```
#wd-faq .outer .slideInDown{
-webkit-animation-name: slideInDown;
animation-name: slideInDown;
-webkit-animation-duration: 80ms;
animation-duration: 80ms;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInDown {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
visibility: visible;
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
}
}
@keyframes slideInDown {
0% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
visibility: visible;
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
}
}
```

Closing Class:

```
#wd-faq .outer .slideOutUp {
 -webkit-animation-name: slideOutUp;
 animation-name: slideOutUp;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 80ms;
 animation-duration: 80ms;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes slideOutUp {
 0% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 transform: translateY(0);
 }
 100% {
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 }
 }
 @keyframes slideOutUp {
 0% {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 transform: translateY(0);
 }
 100% {
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 }
 }
```

Please Help.